# Paginator in django

Tags: django, django-models, pagination, django-templates, django-views

Hi i looking at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/pagination/  documentation about django paginator

in the code it use

```
from django.core.paginator import EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger, Paginator

    from django.shortcuts import render

    def listing(request):
        contact_list = Contacts.objects.all()
        paginator = Paginator(contact_list, 25) # Show 25 contacts per page

        page = request.GET.get('page')
        contacts = paginator.get_page(page)
        return render(request, 'list.html', {'contacts': contacts})
```

And in template it use

```
<div class="pagination">
    <span class="step-links">
        {% if contacts.has_previous %}
            <a href="?page=1">&laquo; first</a>
            <a href="?page={{ contacts.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
        {% endif %}

        <span class="current">
            Page {{ contacts.number }} of {{ contacts.paginator.num_pages }}.
        </span>

        {% if contacts.has_next %}
            <a href="?page={{ contacts.next_page_number }}">next</a>
            <a href="?page={{ contacts.paginator.num_pages }}">last &raquo;</a>
        {% endif %}
    </span>
</div>
```

I understand all the codes except in first time render what will be value of **page**

In the line

> page = request.GET.get('page')

i know django run

> ?page=Value

and pass value to page argumant but what was the value of page in first render

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`page` will be `None` in that case and `get_page` will then return the first page.

Comment: Thanks and then None will be 1  in the paginator

Comment: No, `contacts = paginator.get_page(page)` where `page=None` i.e `contacts = paginator.get_page(None)` return first page and if in the query params there is ?page=3 then `page` will be 3

Comment: Thanks very much for your help